# add class to html label at runtime asp net

Tags: css, asp.net, label

I work on asp.NET, coding on server side with C#.

In the "view" part, I only have a label in my body, which is server side :

**HTML**

```
<label runat="server" id="html_label_1"></label>
```

I would like to change its class at runtime. Here is my 2 CSS classes :

**CSS**

```
.label_error {
    color : red;
}

.label_success {
    color : green;
}
```

I created 2 functions in C# (server side), which change the text of this label and should add the proper class like following :

**C#**

```
protected void displayError(object error) 
{
    string err = error.ToString();

    html_label_1.InnerText = err;
    /* this is where I want to toggle class to ".label_error" */
}

protected void displaySuccess(object success) 
{
    string succ = success.ToString();

    html_label_1.InnerText = succ;
    /* this is where I want to toggle class to ".label_success" */
}
```

**My Problem :**

I didn't see any properties to set my own class. When [CTRL]+[SPACE] on server side on `html_label_1`, I only see `html_label_1.Style.Add()`, but this methods needs a string with the style, which is not my purpose.

Can anyone lead me to a solution please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using following in code behind:

```
html_label_1.Attributes.Add("class", "label_error");
```

OR

```
html_label_1.CssClass = "label_error"
```